# Таймер на основе Task

Tags: c#, tpl

Помогите довести до ума.. возможно где то что-то не учел.

```
public class TaskTimer : IDisposable
{
    private readonly Task task;

    private TimeSpan timeExecute;

    private bool End;

    private CancellationTokenSource CTS;

    private readonly Action action;

    private readonly object waiter;

    private bool active;

    public void DoAction()
    {
        bool actionEnd = true;
        while(true)
        {
            lock (waiter)
            {
                while (!active || !actionEnd)
                    Monitor.Wait(waiter);
                if (End)
                    return;
            }
            Task.Delay(timeExecute, CTS.Token)
                .ContinueWith((t) => action(), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion)
                .ContinueWith((t) => { lock (waiter) { actionEnd = true; Monitor.Pulse(waiter); } });
            actionEnd = false;
        }
    }

    public TaskTimer(TaskCreationOptions TCO, Action action, TimeSpan TS)
    {
        CTS = new CancellationTokenSource();
        End = false;
        timeExecute = TS;
        waiter = new object();
        active = false;
        this.action = action;
        task = Task.Factory.StartNew(DoAction, TCO);
    }

    public bool Active
    {
        get { return active; }
        set
        {
            lock (waiter)
            {
                active = value;
                Monitor.Pulse(waiter);
            }
            if (!active)
            {
                CTS.Cancel();
                CTS.Dispose();
                CTS = new CancellationTokenSource();
            }
        }
    }

    #region IDisposable implementation

    public void Dispose()
    {
        lock (waiter)
        {
            End = true;
            CTS.Cancel();
            Monitor.Pulse(waiter);
        }
        Task.WaitAll(task);
        CTS.Dispose();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Это C# 5? Почему не async/await?

Comment: Не использовал дабы не запутать самого себя. Если покажете как это можно сделать правильно с помощью async/await буду рад

Comment: А какое в точности задание? Что должно происходить, объясните на словах.

Comment: Написать таймер на основе Task, который по истечении определенного времени запускал действие, с возможностью установки таймера на паузу с корректной отменой задания.

Comment: А как должно задание ставиться на _паузу_?

Comment: здесь можно рассмотреть в принципе два варианта. Первый это ставить блокировку внутрь вечного цикла или просто делать выход из цикла а при запуске создавать задачу заново.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, вы хотите просто

```
async Task ExecuteAfterWithCancellation(TimeSpan ts, Action a, CancellationToken ct)
{
    await Task.Delay(ts, ct);
    a();
}
```

---

Для постоянного перезапуска подойдёт такое:

```
async Task ExecuteWithTimeoutAndCancellation(TimeSpan ts, Action a, CancellationToken ct)
{
    var timeout = Task.Delay(ts, ct);
    while (true)
    {
        await timeout;
        timeout = Task.Delay(ts, ct); // начинаем отсчитывать время
                                      // до запуска задания
        a();
    }
}
```

Если вы хотите отсчитывать время от момента *после* выполнения задания, можно проще:

```
async Task ExecuteWithTimeoutAndCancellation(TimeSpan ts, Action a, CancellationToken ct)
{
    while (true)
    {
        await Task.Delay(ts, ct);
        a();
    }
}
```

Comment: Боюсь я выразился не много не точно.. "который по истечении определенного времени запускал действие" постоянно через определенный промежуток времени

Comment: то что вы написали как раз соответсвует:
Task.Delay(timeExecute, CTS.Token)
                .ContinueWith((t) => action(), TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion)

Comment: Задача именно просто написать таймер (с тем же функционалом что и обычный) на основе Task. С минимальной нагрузкой на процессор.

Comment: @Vadim: Написал второй вариант.

Comment: разве при вызове у CancellationTokenSource метода Cancel(), в await timeout не будет генерироваться исключение? Скорее всего строка ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested() является лишней? И timeout = Task.Delay(ts, ct); не надо перенести после a();?

Comment: @Vadim: Ну, разве что если после `Wait` перед a() сработает cancellation. Но да, этим можно пренебречь.

Comment: @Vadim: Если `timeout = Task.Delay` перенести после `а()`, то отсчёт времени начнётся _после_ выполнения `а()`. Если вам надо именно такой подсчёт, то да. Я держал в голове случай, когда ts = 1 сек, а выполнение a() длится 1/3 секунды.

Comment: @Vadim: Всё-таки убрал `ThrowIfCancellationRequested`.

Answer (score 1):

С учетом подсказок VladD, переписал класс таким образом:

```
public sealed class TaskTimer
    {
        private CancellationTokenSource _cts = null;

        private bool _started = false;

        private volatile int  milliseconds = 100;

        public event EventHandler TimerEvent = null;

        private void OnTimerEvent(EventArgs e)
        {
            var handler = TimerEvent;
            if (handler != null)
                handler(this, e);
        }

        private async Task ExecuteWithTimeoutBeforeEvent(CancellationToken ct)
        {
            var timeout = Task.Delay(milliseconds, ct);
            while (true)
            {
                await timeout;
                timeout = Task.Delay(milliseconds, ct);
                OnTimerEvent(EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }

        private async Task ExecuteWithTimeoutAfterEvent(CancellationToken ct)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                await Task.Delay(milliseconds, ct);
                OnTimerEvent(EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }

        public void SetInterval(int milliseconds)
        {
            this.milliseconds = milliseconds;
        }

        public int GetInterval()
        {
            return milliseconds;
        }

        public async Task Start(bool startTimeAfterEvent = false)
        {
            if (_started)
                return;
            _started = true;

            _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            try
            {
                if (startTimeAfterEvent)
                    await ExecuteWithTimeoutAfterEvent(_cts.Token);
                else
                    await ExecuteWithTimeoutBeforeEvent(_cts.Token);
            }
            catch (TaskCanceledException)
            { }
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            if (!_started)
                return;
            _started = false;
            _cts.Cancel();
            _cts.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Понял что в предыдущей реализации все слишком перемудрил с блокировками и не нужным кодом. Большое спасибо за помощь!